# Code for updating app

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm making a pack of small apps for our fires services and, at the end, we will have about 10 smalls app. In order to avoid the guy to search for the right app, I'll make a "shell" which will show him the list of the app.
Using Intent, I know how to create this shell and use it to send user to the other app.

But, I want also to use this "shell" to update: the shell will connect to our server, compare the version of the app he can run with the version of the last release. And if a new release is avaible, the shell will update the app

So, I've two questions:
- Is it possible to do that? because in my case, the app will not be updated by itself, but througt the shell. So can the shell receive data or may it only open the link to the user? 
- How this can be done, when the shell would have to "self-update"?

I don't want code but idea of "how can I do", because when I search for "updating APP", Google is full of answer for "user" and not for "coders". :(

Comment: `..."updating APP", Google is full of answer for "user" and not for "coders"` ... not true ... problem is that there is no way to update app without user interaction(without root/custom OS) ...

Comment: So you say it's impossible, but there is a lot of answer... And you set -1. Thanks a lot... SO is really a nice place to be.

Comment: @Peter: It depends on your definition of updating. Installing an apk is indeed not possible without root or user interaction. However, apps can be written to be updateable without the system, e.g. by hosting scripts (or dynamic libraries) on a server and downloading and loading them if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. OK, I know I can give an URL to the user. The tips I'm searching for is the way the shell will tell the user "A new version of your app is available, just update it". What seem to be hard would be to have a shell downloading the new version, by itself. In that case, if it's not directly possible, maybe I'll have to send the URL to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your definitions are a bit weird. In my understanding your 'small app' is just a normal Activity and what you call 'shell' is a normal App with a menu to start those Activities. So in my eyes it would be much (much, much) better to provide ONE app insteat of TEN. I would be pretty anoyed if I have to install all of those.

Updates are provided via Google Play, according to the user settings the updates will come automatically. In your question I don't see any need to implement an own update mechanism.

Comment: I'll explain better: the fire servies are ours. So the Apps will not be "public". A fire service need a lot of different small tool. One for verification of hydrant, another for checking point of danger, another used during fire operation and so on. It's not possible to know actually ALL the small app we'll need. What I want is being able to create one app today, another next month and so on and being sure the guys will have all the apps and last version of each.

Comment: @Peter There are ways to distribute _private_ apps over Google Play. Either as beta versions which are only available to persons you assign, or over a [Private Channel](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2623322?hl=en)

Comment: This can be an option. Thanks!